# mongoexport using different collection in query

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Is there any option in mongoexport to use the query on different collection

```
mongoexport --host=“xxx:1111” --db=dbname --pretty --collection=employee --query=‘db.department.find({“departmentId”:10},{“employeeID”:1})’ --out=output.json
```

I want to get the employee records based on the department collection
All the employee , those who belong to deparmentID : 10

```
Db version details
db.version();
4.2.8
```

Comment: The employee collection document has a department field?

Comment: @prasad_ : yes,

Comment: Include sample documents of both collections in your question post. You can only specify the same collection in the query you are exporting from. Tell, why do you want to query department collection when you have department field in employee collection?